# Cannot read and write Userdefaults in sandboxed app

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

I sandboxed my app and since then I´m getting the following errors:

```
2017-12-29 19:31:19.649922+0100 Testapp[74854:12059315] [User Defaults] Failed
to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e0080> (Domain: testapp, User:
kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)): accessing preferences
outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access, detaching from cfprefsd

2017-12-29 19:31:19.893912+0100 Testapp[74854:12059315] [User Defaults] attempt to
set 100 for key in numberOfResults in non-persistent preferences domain
CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e0080> (Domain: testapp, User:
kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null))
```

I´m setting the Userdefaults just like this;

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints")
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: You show only a single line of code and want a stranger to figure out what has gone wrong?

Comment: @ElTomato there is no more. Thats all.

Comment: You can't just write to any file without user's consent.  That's why I've asked you if you have other lines of code to show.  If you could, then why would they require your app be sandboxed in the first place?

Comment: could you post your entitlements file? Is it macOS or iOS?

Comment: I have the same issue, in a more complex project, but it boils down to the same result: it is logging many of these errors (all worded exactly the same.) But it only happens on the first launch, or after deleting the prefs file from the sandbox. Subsequent launches are working fine. Any updates?